# Difference Between OPTICS and HDBSCAN clustering techniques

Tags: cluster-computing, dbscan, optics-algorithm, hdbscan

As a part of my assignment, I have to work on both HDBSCAN and OPTICS  clustering technique. I have researched on many sites to identify the difference between these algorithms. All I  got was OPTICS algorithm is a slight variation from HDBSCAN. I would like to know more about this algorithm. Can someone help me to understand the difference between these algorithms and specific use cases about when do we have to use them?
Also, post reference link for further reading. Thanks

Comment: This is too broad to be answered here. Doesn't the HDBSCAN  paper itself explain how it differs from OPTICS?